# memory check library for MinGW

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector

I need a leak detector tool for application writte in MinGW (4.8.1). Visual Leak Detector seems (not sure) works only with msvc(9,10,11), and the valgrind port on windows seems works only with older version of gcc.

So what tools can I use for memory check my code?

Comment: May be you can use the mpatrol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is two useful links :

- Wu Yongwei's memory leak detector can be found here : http://wyw.dcweb.cn/leakage.htm
- More links may be found here : http://betterlogic.com/roger/?p=1140

Those links are from their [FAQ](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/FAQ).

I also like this one : http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp-memory.php. But it is not free, it has a free 30 days trial. This last one works really good.

Comment: Wu Yongwei's memory leak detector has a critical [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025819/global-overload-operator-new-delete-in-mingw/) with MinGW.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest https://github.com/milostosic/MTuner. It is free, has a cool GUI, handles mingw applications and has everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Deleaker supports MinGW:
https://www.deleaker.com/blog/2022/03/14/memory-leak-detection-tool-for-mingw/

Also it integrates with Qt Creator that seems to be the most popular IDE that supports MinGW.