# Why is delete not getting called?

Tags: c++, overloading, new-operator

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void* operator new(size_t size){
    cout << "overloading new operator with size " << size << endl;
    void* p= malloc(size);
    return p;
}

void operator delete(void * p){
    cout << "Overloaded delete operator " << endl;
    free(p);
}



int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    int* x = new int;
    delete x;
    return 0;
}
```

I am expecting to see overloaded operator with size 4 and overloaded delete operator but instead I am only seeing overloaded operator with size 4.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? With `MSVC` *both* overloads are called; with `clang-cl` *neither* is called!!

Comment: I am seeing the overloaded delete operator called with `g++-9` and the version of `clang` bundled with OS X.

Comment: I am using MinGW

Comment: What is your compilation command and what compiler/version are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global overload operator new/delete in MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025819/global-overload-operator-new-delete-in-mingw)

Comment: TLDR: [gcc bug on Windows](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77726), define `operator delete(void*, size_t)` as workaround.