# GCC: How to verify that the heap is empty?

Tags: gcc, malloc, heap-memory

I have written some code that uses malloc() and free(). And I have implemented a module test program on GCC/ MinGW that tests this code. At some point, I would like to verify that all of the heap has been freed.

I have tried to malloc() some heap, take the pointer and free it directly afterwards - regarding the pointer value as "heap state", and comparing it to the state at the beginning. This is often working, but sometimes I see changes in the pointer, while I am sure the tested code has not changed.

What is the correct way to check the heap state, or at least to check that all heap is free?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855662/memory-check-library-for-mingw answer your question? You might want to research: code instrumentation, address sanitizer, valgrind, static analysis.

Comment: Use existing tools (valgrind, address sanitizers, debugging malloc libraries). Do not reinvent the wheel, unless it's a better wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wrap all calls to allocation-related functions with your own wrappers, a simple approach is to have your wrappers increment a counter every time something is allocated and decrement the counter every time something is freed.  If using multi-threaded code, you should use some form counter that can be updated atomically.

A slight enhancement is to have allocation code request 16 or 32 bytes more than the application, and place a header at the start of each allocation including its size and/or an index into a table of outstanding allocations the program has made (if you can establish a reasonable bound on the total number of allocations, the table could be maintained in static-duration storage).  If allocations are done via macro, the macro could pass your allocation function the contents of the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros at the point where the allocation is called.  If any allocations are performed but never released, this would let you find where in the program the allocations had been performed.